# Why is the performance time graph of the Fibonacci function not smooth?

Tags: python, algorithm

There are two functions that implement Fibonacci sequence. `fibo()` was recursive style, and `iterfibo()` was implemented using a circular method.
I compared the performance time of the two functions.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

# iteration style
def iterfibo(count):
    if count <= 1 :
        return count

    left, right = 0, 1

    for i in range(count - 1):
        temp = left + right
        left = right
        right = temp

    return temp

# recursion style
def fibo(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    return fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2)

length = [x for x in range(25)]

iterfibo_time = []
fibo_time = []

for i in length:
    # fibo's execution time
    ts = time.time()
    fibo(i)
    fibo_time.append(time.time() - ts)

    # iterfibo's execution time
    ts = time.time()
    iterfibo(i)
    iterfibo_time.append(time.time() - ts)

plt.plot(length, iterfibo_time)
plt.show()
```

However, I was wondering that the graph of `iterfibo()` was not a smooth curve. And in some cases, the performance time was reduced, not increased.

`fibo()` (recursive) time:
[image: fibo_time.png]

`iterfibo()` (iterative) time:
[image: iterfibo_time.png]

So I wonder why the graph takes this form.

Comment: `iterfibo` is way too fast to time like this.

Comment: For Performances and code review related questions prefer https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should take a look at the standard `timeit` module.

Comment: As user2357112 mentioned timings in milliseconds range vary a lot, so try to get at least in a range of about 1s (so run the algorithm at least 1.000.000 times and time it and divide the result by this number. The graph should look much smoother).

Comment: BTW, you can improve `iterfibo` a little. See if you can rewrite it without `temp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted in a comment, the calculation times of `iterfibo()` are too small to be accurately measured with `time()`. So the variations are just cause by measurement inaccuracy and are meaningless.

The step around n=26 could be caused by a switch from 16 to 32 bit integers. F(25)=46368 can be represented with 16 bits while F(27)=75025 requires 32 bit integers.

Comment: The Python `int` object uses machine-word size integers for small integer values, and switches to arbitrary precision for larger numbers. So 32 bit Python uses 32 bits for small numbers, and 64 bit Python uses 64 bit. You can create other integer sizes using `ctypes`, or Numpy, but that's not relevant for the OP's code.

Comment: So, integer size is irrelevant to that spike, which could be due to random system load variation, or Python's memory recycling system doing stuff in the background. That recursive `fibo` creates an awful lot of junk that needs to be collected. FWIW, the `timeit` module disables garbage collection during timings.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithms you described for computing the *n*-th Fibonacci number are not the fastest. The fastest possible algorithms (for large *n*) are based on different recursive formulations. Since you are probably not interested to the theoretical details underlying the algorithms, here is, for your reference, a "practical" paper discussing the Python implementation of 12 different algorithms. These algorithms are compared against each other for different ranges of *n*, and the results are discussed. You will see that, depending on the value of *n*, the best algorithm changes.

[Twelve Simple Algorithms to Compute Fibonacci Numbers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.07199.pdf)